# Calculate the probability that more than one of the five machines is defective.

Tags: probability

There are five machines.

Let N be the exact number of defective machines.

You are given:

$\quad{}\quad{}\begin{array}{c|c} {N} & {\text{Probability}} \\ \hline 0 & 0.06 \\ 1 & 0.15 \\ 2 & 0.10 \\ 3 & 0.20 \\ 4 & 0.25 \\ 5 & 0.24 \\ \hline\end{array}$

A machine can either be defective or not defective. Given more than one of the five machines is not defective, calculate the probability that more than one of the five machines is defective.

From first glance I thought I could just do ${1-.06-.15}\over.15$ but then I realized that this was very wrong when I re-read the question. The next attempt was:

$X=\text { Probability of defective and  } Y= \text{ Probability of not defective}$ 
$$P(X>1|Y>1)={P(X>1)\cap P(Y>1)\over P(Y>1)}$$ $$P(Y>1)=1-P(Y\leq1)=1-(1-.06)-(1-.15)$$but I get stuck at this point, I'm unsure of what to do from here because that gives me a negative probability.

Answer (score 1):

In your equations you have $X+Y=5$, so the equation for $P(Y>1)$ is $$P(Y>1) = P(X<4) = 0.06+0.15+0.10+0.20=0.51$$

On the other hand, you can calculate $$P(X>1\cap Y>1)=P(X = 2,3) = 0.10+0.20=0.30$$
So the probability is $$P(X>1|Y>1)=\frac{0.30}{0.51}=\frac{10}{17}$$

Comment: Wait, how come $$P(X>1 \cap Y>1) = P(X=2,3) \text{ instead of }P(X=2,Y=3)+P(X=3,Y=2)$$ so .6?

Comment: My notation for $P(X=2,3)$ means $P(X = 2 \ or \ X = 3) = P(X = 2,Y=3) + P(X=3,Y=2)$ $= 0.1+0.2 = 0.3 $

Comment: Ah forgive me, I was counting $P(X=2,Y=3)$ as $.1+.2$ when really it is just $.1$

Answer (score 1):

There was no need to use $X$ and $Y$. You can recast the whole problem in terms of $N$.

It is given that more than one machine is not defective (= working). This means that $N$ cannot be $5$ since this would imply that there were **no** working machines. Further, $N$ cannot be $4$ because this would imply that there was **exactly** one working machine. Hence, $N\leq 3$.

So we are asked to find $P(N>1|N\leq 3)$:
$$P(N>1|N\leq 3) = \frac{P(1<N\leq 3)}{P(N\leq 3)} = \frac{.10+.20}{.06+.15+.10+.20} = \frac{10}{17}.$$

If you really wanted to use $X$ and $Y$, then it might  be helpful to organize the values. First, $X$ *counts* is the number of defective machines (not the *probability*), and $Y$ counts the number of machines that are not defective (= working). Then we have the following. Notice that $X$ is really the $N$ provided in the problem, but I provide it for completeness.
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n & X & Y & P(N = n)\\\hline
0 & 0 & 5 & .06\\\hline
1 & 1 & 4 & .15\\\hline
\color{red}2 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}3 & \color{red}{.10}\\\hline
\color{red}3 & \color{red}3 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}{.20}\\\hline
4 & 4 & 1 & .25\\\hline
5 & 5 & 0 & .24
\end{array}

Then 
$$P(X>1|Y>1) = \frac{P(\color{red}{X>1 \cap Y>1})}{P(Y>1)} = \frac{\color{red}{.10+.20}}{.20+.10+.15+.06} = \frac{10}{17}.$$